# Why does fgetc put the file offset at the end of the file?

Tags: c

I have a simple test program that uses `fgetc()` to read a character from a file stream and `lseek()` to read a file offset. It looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    char buf[] = "hello world";
    FILE *f;
    int fd;

    fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
    write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

    f = fdopen(fd, "r");

    printf("%c\n", fgetc(f));
    printf("%d\n", lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR));
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
h
12
```

The return value of `fgetc(f)`, `h`, makes sense to me. But why is it repositioning the file offset to be at the end of the file? Why doesn't `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` give me 1?

If I repeat the the first print statement, it works as expected and prints an `e` then an `l` etc.

I don't see any mention of this weird behavior in the `man` page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stdio functions like `fgetc` are buffered.  They will `read()` a large block into a buffer and then return characters from the buffer on successive calls.

Since the default buffer size is more than 12 (usually many KB), the first time you `fgetc()`, it tries to fill its buffer which means reading the entire file.  Thus `lseek` returns a position at the end of the file.

If you want to get a file position that takes into account what's still in the buffer, use `ftell()` instead.